# Salto de Linea en JSON.NET

Tags: json

en vb.net estoy creando una clase persona y el objeto resultante tiene los campos Id, Nombre, Edad. Luego usando JSON.NET convierto ese objeto en un archivo .json y lo guardo en el disco duro pero al abrirlo todo queda en una sola lineea asi:

```
{"Id":4,"Nombre":"Juan Perez","Edad":18}
```

Yo quisiera que aparezca asi

```
{
 "Id":4,
 "Nombre":"Juan Perez",
 "Edad":18
}
```

Es decir con salto de lineas...necesito ayuda con esto...gracias

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta mostrada?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te va un ejemplo:

clase:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Utilizando en el "formateo" adecuado:

```
Account account = new Account
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "User",
        "Admin"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
// {
//   "Email": "james@example.com",
//   "Active": true,
//   "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
//   "Roles": [
//     "User",
//     "Admin"
//   ]
// }

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Extraído de la documentación oficial: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm